# Wrong sync Folder Mapping in Vagrant with Windows

Tags: windows, vagrant, synchronization, shared

I use Vagrant for Web-Development with a Windows Host.
However I seem to have a strange problem and Digging all sorts of Google results wont hand me any solution for this.

**Problem:**

I have a Sync Folder defined in windows with this stucture
D:/VM/tutorial-test/vagrant/VagrantFile
D:/VM/tutorial-test/vagrant/tutorial/index.php

So the VagrantFile is configured to use the Folder "tutorial" to mount as Sync folder.
This is in Linux a subfolder of "/var/www"

Half of the time it mounts verything right.
The subfolder gets mounted and I can add and remove Files.
The other Half while "vagrant up" is running, it seems like he Mounts a different Windows folder. Its mostly 1 or 2 Folder back in the Tree where my VagrantFile sits.

Here is my VagrantFile:

```rb
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32" 
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh" 
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "after-boot.sh", run: "always"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 80, guest: 80
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.50.50'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "vhosts/", "/etc/apache2/sites-available",
    owner: "root", group: "root"
  config.vm.synced_folder "tutorial/", "/var/www/tutorial",
    owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

end
```

What happens when I initiate a "vagrant up"

[image]

As you can see, it mounts the "D:/VM" Folder.
The actual structure here should be D:/VM/tutorial-test/vagrant/tutorial
There are more than 1 Sync Folder defined. He acts equaly with every Sync Folder.

There must be something, that confuses the Vagrant Setup Script.

**EDIT:**

I did some more tests. It seems like the Vagrantfile get correctly readed, but the Vagrant Root is going to be 2 levels up in the Windows File tree.

**EDIT 2:**

The User Emyl brought me on the Track that maybe my Calling Script is broken. Using the normal Shell is working.
Because of this im Posting the Bash Script I wrote, since it's Open Source anyway:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >>     "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

cls
dir
cd %~dp0
dir
cd vagrant
dir
:start
echo Please select an Option:
echo -------------------------
echo 1: Start Vagrant VM
echo 2: Reload Vagrant VM
echo 3: Shutdown Vagrant VM
echo 4: Suspend Vagrant VM
echo 5: Destroy Vagrant VM (see Note)
echo 6: Command Line (for other commands)
echo 7: Exit
echo -------------------------
echo Note: Destroy will uninstall the VM, exept the Files in the Vagrant Folder! &     echo.Please create a Database-Dump before destroying the VM, to prevent Data-Loss.
echo -------------------------
set /p choice=Enter a Number: 
if '%choice%'=='1' goto :up
if '%choice%'=='2' goto :reload
if '%choice%'=='3' goto :halt
if '%choice%'=='4' goto :suspend
if '%choice%'=='5' goto :destroy
if '%choice%'=='6' goto :command
if '%choice%'=='7' goto :end
echo %Choice% is not a valid option. Please try again.
echo ...
goto :start
:up
vagrant up
goto :start
:reload
vagrant reload
goto :start
:halt
vagrant halt
goto :start
:suspend
vagrant suspend
goto :start
:destroy
vagrant destroy
goto :start
:command
set /p command=Enter Command: 
call %%command%%
goto :start
:end
pause
exit
```

**EDIT 3:**

The Problem relys on calling the File with a Batch Script.
The Problem are long Path names which get shortened by Windows like TUTORI~2.
This seems to break Vagrants Env Variable generation.

**EDIT 4 - Solution:**

As mentioned I was calling Vagrant with a Batch Script.
Vagrant doesnt liked the shortened URLS generated by my CMD when using the Location of the current Script with "%~dp0".
The Solution as described here:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915666/windows-batch-getting-path-without-shortening)

With this snippet I am able to create a windows Path. Using this Path will cause Vagrant no Issues anymore and my Sync Folder is generated properly.

Comment: Sounds like a VirtualBox issue. Just to be sure, if you can, update VirtualBox to latest version and also update guest additions for the vm, and check if the problem goes away.

Comment: I am still parallel searching for my Own for a solution.
I also came Across this GuestAdditions thing, so I installed the appropiate Vagrant Plugin mentioned in Tutorials. 
Sadly this didnt fix my Problem, I will try to check my VBox Version next.

Comment: @Emyl Sorry I had some days off vor exam learning. I tryed VirtualBox 4.3.14 but this build is broken for Windows. So the only Version I can use is the 4.3.12 which should be a working Version for Vagrant 1.6.3.
So The problem isnt solved still. :\

Comment: have you also checked guest additions? From the screenshot they seem outdated. If unsure you can install the vagrant-vbguest plugin to update it automatically.

Comment: also, if guest addition update don't solve your problem, please run SET VAGRANT_LOG=debug, then run vagrant up > debug.log and, if the mount fail post a gist with logs.

Comment: Sadly it did'nt log the advanded Debugs but they where shown in the Console. Other than that the Problem doesnt appear now. Interestingly I have run the vagrant up with Admin Rights, I may be on a Tack here.

I use a Batch Script to control my VM a bit more comfortable. Maybe the Problem relys on a wrong path mapping. I will investigate and give Reply.

Comment: Ok I now ran some tests. I am suspecting the Windows Shell to produce Path errors since long folder Names get resembled as something like "tutoria~2". So I made a ned folder called "a" so the Path is D:\VM\a\vagrant  and it works now. O.O