# Windows Batch: getting Path without Shortening

Tags: windows, batch-file

I searched now for several Hours and didnt find any fitting solution for me.

When I try to get the current Path of the Batch File, I use normaly %~dp0.
This will leads in Paths like: D:\VM\TUTORI~2\STARTS~1.BAT

However this is not an issue, if only doing File Management, but I want to use the Script to call Vagrant commands. 
It happens that the Vagrant System doesnt like this shortened Paths. 
As soon as the Path is short enough or when I call it from the CMD directly, it works just fine.

I'm now searching for a way to get any unshortened Path to my working Directory.
But whatever I tried so far didnt work and google only delivers me how people Shorten their Paths.
Is there a practical Solution to this Problem?

I want to set a Variable in my Script looking like this:
D:\VM\tutorialtest

**EDIT:**

According to the Accepted Answer the working snippet for me is the Snippet without the "-2" on the 2. For Loop. This will give me the Path no matter where the folder is.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myPath=%~DP0
set myPath=%myPath:*\=%
set fullPath=
pushd \
for %%a in ("%myPath:\=" "%") do (
   set thisDir=%%~a
   for /D %%d in ("!thisDir:~0!*") do (
      set fullPath=!fullPath!\%%d
      cd %%d
   )
)
popd
echo Full path: %~D0%fullPath%
```

Result:

```
D:\VM\tutorialtest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "myPath=%~DP0"
set "myPath=%myPath:*\=%"
set "fullPath="
pushd \
for %%a in ("%myPath:\=" "%") do (
   set "thisDir=%%~a"
   for /D %%d in ("!thisDir:~0,-2!*") do (
      set "fullPath=!fullPath!\%%d"
      cd "%%d"
   )
)
popd
echo Full path: %~D0%fullPath%
```

Post the result, please.

**EDIT**: *Bug fixed*

The problem is that names that have less than 2 characters are cutted! (my mistake).

I did some testing and it seems that `for /D %%d in ("TUTORI~2*") ...` also returns the full name of the folder, so thisDir variable is not required. You may modify the `for %%a` loop this way and get the same result:

```
for %%a in ("%myPath:\=" "%") do (
   for /D %%d in ("%%~a*") do (
      set fullPath=!fullPath!\%%d
      cd %%d
   )
)
```

Comment: I have edited the snipped a bit and added some echos to see what is happening. Sadly this didnt work exactly, but it looks like there is just some logic error in there. Here is the Code:

Comment: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myPath=%~DP0
set myPath=%myPath:*\=%
set fullPath=
pushd \
for %%a in ("%myPath:\=" "%") do (
   set thisDir=%%~a
   echo A: %%a
   for /D %%d in ("!thisDir:~0,-2!*") do (
      echo D: %%d
      set fullPath=!fullPath!\%%d
      cd %%d
   )
)
popd
echo Full path: %~D0%fullPath%`

Comment: And the Output is (shortened a bit):
`A: "VM"
D: adobePreview
D: DirectX
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
D: Drivers
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
D: eclipse
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
D: VM
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
D: workspace
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
A: "TUTORI~2"
A: ""
Full path: D:\DirectX\Drivers\eclipse\VM\workspace`

Comment: Found the Problem with this Snippet. You are determing the parts by -2 like I wrote on top, at this place the first Folder is at -1, then i get the right path. Is there a way to generalize the mapping, so it doesnt matter at what Folder Level I call the Script?

Answer (score 1):

Edit - Corrected the code which can work with path with or without spaces.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir ^| findstr /i /c:"Directory of"') do set mypath=%i
set mypath=%mypath: Directory of =%
```

Above codes will work if you type them directly in command console, if you want to use it in batch file use it as below.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir ^| findstr /i /c:"Directory of"') do set mypath=%%i
set mypath=%mypath: Directory of =%
```

I believe you are in need of getting the current working directory(something like pwd in Unix). 'dir' command usually returns the current path details along with variuos other details. We just pick the line with the directory name (line with the tag "Directory of") and then in the second line we remove the tag "Directory of" (replacing it with none).

Refer the below link for more string manipulation techniques.

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Sample output - typed on command console

```
C:\test\new folder>for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir ^| findstr /i /c:"Directory of"') do set mypath=%i

C:\test\new folder>set mypath= Directory of C:\test\new folder

C:\test\new folder>set mypath=%mypath: Directory of =%

C:\test\new folder>echo.%mypath%
```

Comment: This works even with spaces in the path: `for /f "tokens=2*" %i in ('dir ^| findstr /i /c:"Directory of"') do set mypath=%j`

Comment: Great. I don't know much about using * in tokens. Could you please help me to understand it?

Comment: I dont quite understand if I have to edit something here. The Code snippets as they here now, are not working in my Batch script. 
Also a short description of what is happening there would be great.

Comment: I'm unable to get the formatting right in comments section, let me edit my answer and explain you.

Comment: Ah ok, well dir also returns the output as %~dp0 or %cd% would. The problem is the shortening and not the String manipulation. My CMD seems to shorten every long Folder or Filename by default. However the Vagrant System works with ruby and seem to hate these dirs for some reason. Acinis Answer worked for me so far.

Comment: But anyway, good to know that, others will maybe stumble across that Information and may find it usefull.

Comment: @Panade. That's weird. My command (on Win7) always returns the full path and not the shortened form. Which version of OS you use here?

Comment: Windows 7 pro x64. I think its a Windows Configuration why this happens. Also my Script calls for Administrative rights, which also may take a step into that. I use this Script as a ultra lightweight vagrant interface to share with other people not that familar with Vagrant. I am also not Windows Batch expert, so I dont know if I missed something terribly.

Comment: Could you go to any folder on your system on command and type dir /x. What is the output? This usually gives both shortened and full folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
set $path=%cd%
echo %$path%
```

Comment: Tryed that in my Script now, but didnt help. 
All this does is using the %cd% variable, this var however is also shortened.

I think a way to revert this shortening should be existing anywhere.

Comment: Are you using `command.com` because `cmd.exe` doesn't use short names by default?

Comment: Its the normal windows cmd.exe
However I have read somewhere that Windows 7 defaults it to path shortening. This Script however should be designed to work without any further system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If this behaviour occurs when you open a cmd window, then type `echo %comspec%` at the cmd prompt and see what it returns: if it has `command.com` as part of it then it has been altered.

Another possibility is that the shortcut you are using to open a `cmd window` has `command.com` in the properties to launch it.

If you **are** using a shortcut then try to open a cmd prompt from the Win+R hotkey and type `cmd` and enter.   See if this behaviour has changed but also check the first point above once more.